# Launch PUTTY script in C# code

Tags: c#, unix, putty

I need to write a C# code that uses PUTTY to connect to a UNIX server, execute a command (for example "ls -la") , and get back the results of the script to C#.
How can I do it?

I use Process.Start in C# to run the PUTTY process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2):

What you need in-order to get the results from your Putty Process is to redirect your processes `stdout (Standard Output)` stream and consume it in your code:

```
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\PuttyLocation",
        Arguments = @"-ssh -b abc.txt"
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false, // You have to set ShellExecute to false
        ErrorDialog = false
    };

    var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    if (process == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var reader = process.StandardOutput;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        // Read data..
    }
```

Comment: OK. and how do i pass parameters to PUTTY ? for example if i want to write - putty.exe -ssh -b abc.txt mgroiser@icsl9932  .

Comment: In `ProcessStartInfo`, use the Arguments property. Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: ok. my Putty is located at C:\tmp\putty.exe . and my abc.txt file is located there as well, but if i do as you wrote (without specifing the full path to abc.txt), it can't find the file . I did var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\tmp\putty.exe",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false, // You have to set ShellExecute to false
                ErrorDialog = false,
                Arguments = "-ssh -m abc.txt mgroiser@icsl9932"
            };

Comment: i put the file in my bin/debug folder just for testing. the process starts, but i don't get anything in the process.StarndardOutput . abc.txt file contains "ls -la" command